# library caret Loading required package: lattice Loading required package: ggplot2 R

Tags: r

```
library(caret)
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: ggplot2
```

I already installed  lattice, ggplot2, since I used `install.packages("caret", dependencies = TRUE)`. Nothing is working. Help!

Comment: Hi FYi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you better describe what you are trying to achieve and how you know it isn't working?

Comment: If all you are concerned about is the messages about loading required packages, those are normal. They are not errors.

Answer (score 0):

A package loading other required packages is normal behavior in R. To confirm that `caret` has been loaded, one can run the following code.

```
library(caret)

loaded_packages  <- library()$results[,1]

# confirm caret is loaded
"caret" %in% tolower(loaded_packages)
```

...and the output:

```
> # confirm caret is loaded
> "caret" %in% tolower(loaded_packages)
[1] TRUE
>
```